# Summation with the Floor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, power-series

How to show this 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} [x+\frac{k}{n}]= [nx]$$
for every $x\in \mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Where the function $[x] = \max\{p \in\mathbb{N}: p\leq x\}$ is the floor function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $m=[nx]$. We write the long division of $m$ by $n$: $m=nq+r$ where $0\le r<n-1$ so

$$ nq+r\le nx<nq+r+1$$
hence
$$q+\frac rn \le x<q+\frac{r+1}{n}$$
so
$$q+\frac{r+k}{n}\le x+\frac kn<q+\frac{k+r+1}{n}$$
so if $k+r<n$ then $[x+\frac kn]=q$ and if $k+r\ge n$ then $[x+\frac kn]=q+1$
and finally
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[x+\frac kn]=\sum_{k=0}^{n-r-1}[x+\frac kn]+\sum_{k=n-r}^{n-1}[x+\frac kn]=(n-r)q+(r-1)(q+1)=m$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Use these facts

> $1\to $ Let $x=i+f$ where $i$ is the integer part and $f$ the fractional part.
>
> $2\to$ $\exists \ 0\le f_0\le n-1$ such that ${f_0\over n}\le f\lt{f_0+1\over n}$
>
> $3\to$ Break the summation into two parts i.e. $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1-f_0}[x+{k\over n}] $ and $\sum\limits_{k=n-f_0}^{n-1}[x+{k\over n}] $
>
> $4\to$ Check that each term of the first summation is same and so are each term in the second summation.

Comment: I may have messes up a bit the limits, but the idea is correct I think.